# Optimise search in JSON with strings in ascending order

Tags: php, json, search, tree

I have this [**JSON**](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c39fb2ede7103f66693e88f8655a8db7) here

At the root, there is a command(property) as `wp` which has 39 sub-commands(sub-properties) as `cache`, `cap`, `checksum`...etc, where each has its own subcommands and this goes up to 4 levels

The better part is that all subcommands are arranged in ascending order, i.e.; strings are arranged in ascending order.

I want to traverse and search whether a command like `wp site create` or `wp term delete` exists in the JSON tree. I don't want to iterate using a `for` loop due to huge time complexity. It's been too long since I've completed my engineering and if my memory serves correctly, a tree structure would greatly improvise the search time.

Can anyone point me to the right direction on achieving this? I'm using PHP as my language.

Comment: `commands` and `sub-commands`? Do you mean `properties` and `nested properties`?

Comment: yes, correct @Script47

Comment: Before using a tree you should build it.

Comment: ***[Formatted version of the OP's JSON.](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c39fb2ede7103f66693e88f8655a8db7)***

Comment: Using the "commands" as keys instead of using an array and setting a `name` property would make this a lot easier.

Comment: @u_mulder, which type of tree would be desirable here?

Comment: Problem is that for building a tree you have to iterate over your array. But you don't want to.

Comment: @SiddharthThevaril if you have to build the tree... you have the same amount of complexity then searching directly in your current structure

Comment: You may try json_decode and array_search()

Comment: @user1844933, array_search() won't do it. I need to search `wp site create` - in that order

Comment: If the items are already sorted - use a binary search, what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here's a binary search solution, you'll need to put your json into a file...
NOTE: because `wp` isn't in a `subcommands` array you can't search for it

```
<?php
function binarySearch(&$myArray, $search, $start, $end)
{
    $middle = ($start + $end) >> 1; // divide by 2
    if ($middle >= $start) {
        if ($search > $myArray[$middle]['name']) { // $search must be in top half of array
            $result = binarySearch($myArray, $search, $middle + 1, $end);
        } elseif ($search < $myArray[$middle]['name']) { // $search must be in bottom half of array
            $result = binarySearch($myArray, $search, $start, $middle - 1);
        } else { // $search is here
            $result = $middle;
        }
    } else {
        $result = false; // $search not found
    }
    return $result;
}

function findCommand($arrFound, $strFind)
{
    $arrFind = explode(' ', $strFind);
    while ($arrFound !== false and list($key, $strCommand) = each($arrFind)) {
        $arrSearch = $arrFound['subcommands'];
        if (($key = binarySearch($arrSearch, $strCommand, 0, count($arrSearch) - 1)) === false) {
            $arrFound = false;
        } else {
            $arrFound = $arrSearch[$key];
        }
    }
    return $arrFound;
}

// get json from file and convert it to an array
$arrJson = json_decode(file_get_contents('items.json'), true);

$arrCommand = findCommand($arrJson, 'site create');
var_dump($arrCommand);

$arrCommand = findCommand($arrJson, 'term delete');
var_dump($arrCommand);
```

Answer (score 0):

though using native functions [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) will probably be quicker

```
<?php
function findCommand($arrFound, $strFind)
{
    $arrFind = explode(' ', $strFind);
    while ($arrFound !== false and list($key, $strCommand) = each($arrFind)) {
        $arrSearch = $arrFound['subcommands'];
        if (($key = array_search($strCommand, array_column($arrSearch, 'name'))) === false) {
            $arrFound = false;
        } else {
            $arrFound = $arrSearch[$key];
        }
    }
    return $arrFound;
}

// get json from file and convert it to an array
$arrJson = json_decode(file_get_contents('items.json'), true);

$arrCommand = findCommand($arrJson, 'site create');
var_dump($arrCommand);

$arrCommand = findCommand($arrJson, 'term delete');
var_dump($arrCommand);
```